# Proving a theorem or statement correct using numbers

Tags: logic

Why is it that you **CAN'T** use numbers to prove a theorem or statement is correct in mathematics but you **CAN** use numbers to prove a theorem or statement is wrong?
e.g:
the triangle inequality |a+b| < |a| + |b| , how could you prove that is correct without using numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Who said you can't?

You can prove a statement of the form "There exists $x$ such that $P(x)$"
by giving an example $x$ for which it is true.

What you can't do with an example is prove a statement of the form "For all $x$, $P(x)$."

Answer (score 3):

Of course you **can** prove theorems with numbers, when these theorems a) have just a finite number of cases or b) are existential statements - but most "interesting" theorems are not of this kind.

It also depends on what you exactly mean by "prove by numbers", e.g. if you work with equivalence classes, you might be able to get away just "with numbers", e.g.:

> Theorem: "All odd square numbers leave a remainder of 1 when divided by 8"
>
> Proof: 1² = 1 (mod 8), 3³ = 1 (mod 8), 5² = 1 (mod 8), 7² = 1
>   (mod 8), q.e.d.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above two answers, I will also reiterate that your statement is not a general one. Existence proofs (E.g. $\exists (x,y): \frac{x}{y} = 2)$ and statement about a finite number of elements (as Landei and Robert have already shown), do not possess this quality.

I think what you are getting at are *universal* statements, like the triangle inequality you gave: $\forall (a,b)\space |a+b|<|a|+|b|$. Any theorem about an *infinite* number of objects which can be re-phrased as "For all P, it is the case that Q" will have the feature that they cannot be proved by enumeration but can be disproved by a single example. Universals possess that challenging combination of strength against proof and fragility against refutation. The root issues is that a single example implies it is not "for all x" or whatever objects you are discussing. However, you need to prove a universal with other universals, not specific instantiations.